# Filtering a django-tables2 table with django-filters using a drop down list

Tags: python, django, django-tables2, django-filters

I have a model (Brief) that i am showing in a list with Django-tables2. A Brief can belong to one or many towers. I am trying to create a view where a user can see all briefs, and then filter to find briefs related to a specific tower. I had first implemented this using check boxes, and it was working, but I need to get that filter into a drop down list.

"GET /brief/?towers= HTTP/1.1" - Gives me all the briefs. 
"GET /brief/?towers=1 HTTP/1.1" - Gives an empty list of briefs.(should give me 2 in my test data)
Querying in django shell gives me the results I would expect.

Another odd behavior is that my drop down list has spaces that can be selected.

```
class Attribute(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='% 
       (class)s_created_by', null=True, blank=True, 
           on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    modified_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='% 
       (class)s_modified_by', null=True, blank=True, 
           on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Tower(Attribute):
    pass


class Brief (Attribute):
   link = models.URLField()
   sources = models.ManyToManyField(SourceSystem)
   format = models.ForeignKey(ReportFormat, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   towers = models.ManyToManyField(Tower)
   type = models.ForeignKey(ReportType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

   def tower_list(self):
      return ", ".join([str(obj) for obj in self.towers.all()])

   def source_list(self):
      return ", ".join([str(obj) for obj in self.sources.all()])
```

My tables.py:

```
class BriefTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.LinkColumn('brief_detail', args=[A('pk')])

    class Meta:
        model = Brief
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        sequence = ('id', 'name', 'type', 'project', 'format',)
        exclude = ('link', 'created_on', 'created_by', 'modified_dt', 'modified_by', 'info')
```

My filters.py

```
class BriefFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    towers=django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Tower.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select)
    class Meta:
        model = Brief
        fields = ['towers']
```

my view:

```
class FilteredBriefListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, 
    FilterView):
    table_class = BriefTable
    template_name = 'brief/brief_list.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    filterset_class = BriefFilter
```

finally my route:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', FilteredBriefListView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking a little break I realized I'm using ModelMultipleChoiceFilter with a single choice instead of ModelChoiceFilter... /facepalm.